# How to generate ~100kHz clock signal in Liunx kernel module with bit-banging?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to generate clock signal on GPIO pin (ARM platform, mach-davinci, kernel 2.6.27) which will have something arroung 100kHz. Using tasklet with high priority to do that. Theory is simple, set gpio high, udelay for 5us, set gpio low, wait  another 5us, but strange problems appear. First of all, can't get this 5us of dalay, but it's fine, looks like hw performance problem, so i moved to period = 40us (gives ~25kHz). Second problem is worst. Once per ~10ms udelay waits 3x longer than usual. I'm thinking that it's hearbeat taking this time, but this is is unacceptable from protocol (which will be implemented on top of this) point of view. Is there any way to temporary disable heartbeat procedure, lets say, for 500ms ? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong from the beginning? Any comments?

Comment: No sure I understand. You are writing a tasklet that would busywait in an infinite loop !?

Comment: Basically yes, but not inifinite, I need that clock for, lets say 500ms, it should be even closer to 300ms. Yes, I'm aware that it'll block everything, but what choice do I have? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use tasklet for this kind of job. Tasklets can be preempted by interrupts. In some case your tasklet can be even executed in the process context!

If you absolutely have to do it this way, use an interrupt handler - get in, disable interrupts, do whatever you have to do and get out as fast as you can.

Comment: Oh... Your description is very different from what I've read, but everything says that you have right, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Generating the clock asynchronously in software is not the right thing to do. I can think of two alternatives that will work better:

1. Your processor may have a built-in clock generator peripheral that isn't already being used by the kernel or another driver. When you set one of these up, you tell it how fast to run its clock, and it just starts running out the pulses.

   Get your processor's datasheet and study it.

   You might not find a peripheral called a "clock" *per se*, but might find something similar that you can press into service, like a PWM peripheral.
2. The other device you are talking to may not actually require a regular clock. Some chips that need a "clock" line merely need a line that goes high when there is a bit to read, which then goes low while the data line(s) are changing. If this is the case, the 100 kHz thing you're reading isn't a hard requirement for a clock of exactly that frequency, it is just an upper limit on how fast the clock line (and thus the data line(s)) are allowed to transition.

   With a CPU so much faster than the clock, you want to split this into two halves:

   - The "top half" sets the data line(s) state correctly, then brings the clock line up. Then it schedules the bottom half to run 5 μs later, using an interrupt or kernel timer.
   - In the "bottom half", called by the interrupt or timer, bring the clock line back down, then schedule the top half to run again 5 μs later.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can run your timer tasklet at higher priority than the kernel timer, you will always be susceptible to this kind of jitter.  You do really have to do this by bit-ganging?  It would be far easier to use a hardware timer or PWM generator.  Configure the timer to run at your desired rate, set the pin to output, and you're done.

If you need software control on each bit period, you can try and work around the other tasks by setting your tasklet to run at a short period, say three-fourths of your 40 us delay.  In the tasklet, disable interrupts and poll the clock until you get to the correct 40 us timeslot, set the I/O state, re-enable interrupts, and exit.  But this effectively types up 25 % of your system in watching a clock.

Comment: Easiest way to do that will be take some hw interface to do the job, like USART or sth, unfortunatelly, everything is taken :(